# How to deal with nested form and strong parameters in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a rails 4 application where I try to fill Post and Detail models.
The relation between the models is has_one.
I PostController I have :

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :email, :tel, :detail_attributes => [:id, :description, :post_id])
end
```

and my form is :

```
<%= f.fields_for @post.detail do |builder| %>
  <%= render "detail_form", detail: builder%>
<% end %>
```

`
When I inspect post_params I get : 
{"title"=>"", "email"=>"toto@example.com", "tel"=>""}

How can I whitelist detail attributes?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :detail
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :detail, allow_destroy: true
end

<%= form_for @ost do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :detail do |builder| %>
    <%= render "detail_form", detail: builder%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line for StrongParameters' `require`/`permit` code looks right. Like Prashant4224 answered, did you include the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your model.rb?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :detail
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :detail
end
```

Sidenote: if you choose to add `allow_destroy: true`, you will need to add `_destroy` to your permit line in your controller like so:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :email, :tel, :detail_attributes => [:id, :description, :post_id, :_destroy])
end
```

If you already have accepted nested parameters in your model, your form may be failing to send those parameters. You should inspect the parameters before post_params is called, and debug your view code from there.

Comment: I second the idea of inspecting both params and post_params, making it easier to see where the problem is occurring: in the params being passed in, or the post_params method.